# On Which Port Couchdb Replication will be done

Tags: curl, couchdb

I have two CouchDB databases running on two machines (SystemA and SystemB). Their URLs are

```
http://SystemA:5984/_utils
http://SystemB:5984/_utils
```

Replication is done from SystemA to SystemB using the following command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
        -X POST http://SystemB:5984/_replicate -d 
        '{
            "source": "http://SystemA:5984/foo", 
            "target": "foo"
        }'
```

On which port is the data being transferred?

Answer (score 1):

Replication uses the `_changes` feed of the source database, so it accesses the database as any other process would. Thus the port is 5984.

Comment: Is this true? I thought replication was done on a different port than whatever was set up. The reason I ask is because vpns and firewalls have been a problem for me getting replication to work.